# If two different shipping classes exist in cart then only show 1 specific shipping class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to achieve the following in Woocommerce:

Inside my webshop i have two shipping classes.

- Flat rate
- Lockal pickup

When both shipping classes are inside the cart i would like to hide the "Flat rate shipping option/cost"

All help is aprreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use woocommerce 'woocommerce_package_rates' filter hooks. check my below code.

```
function only_show_one_specific_shipping_class( $rates ) {
        
    $free = array();

    $local_pickup = $flat_rate = false;
    
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( $rate->method_id === 'local_pickup' ) {
            $local_pickup = true;
        }
        if ( $rate->method_id === 'flat_rate' ) {
            $flat_rate = true;
        }
    }
 
    if( $local_pickup && $flat_rate ){
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'only_show_one_specific_shipping_class', 100 );
```

Comment: Hi Bhautik,

Thank you for your reply. I tried your solution but it is not working.

What am i missing?

Comment: where did you add this code?

Comment: Hi Bhautik,

Apologies for the late reply.

Comment: I have been struggling:

I now have the below code but still no luck:

Comment: // UNSET A SHIPPING METHOD FOR PACKAGE BASED ON THE SHIPPING CLASS(es) OF ITS CONTENTS
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class_combined', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class_combined( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
        
        $class = array(247 && 248);
    }

Comment: foreach( $package['contents'] as $package_item ){ // Look at the shipping class of each item in package

        $product_id = $package_item['product_id']; // Grab product_id
        $_product   = wc_get_product( $product_id ); // Get product info using that id

        
        if(in_array($_product->get_shipping_class_id() == $class )){
            
       
            unset($rates['local_pickup:5']); // Then remove this shipping method
            break; // Stop the loop, since we've already removed the shipping method from this package
        }
    }
    return $rates;

}

Comment: @LeroyWubbels can you edit your question and show us? what code you tried. and in which file you put this code with.